# why is my iphone 5c opening apps uncontrollably by itself?

Tags: iphone

my iPhone 5c is opening/ closing apps and typing randomly and uncontrollably without me touching the screen or even holding the phone, I am now also locked out of my phone because it has typed the wrong passcode in by itself and is disabled for 1 hour. what can I do to fix this and what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

An appointment at the Genius Bar can confirm, but it's likely a hardware problem with a component called the digitizer, which translates touches on the screen into input the phone can understand. Sounds like it is malfunctioning.

Can you lower the phone off and on again? Is the problem constant or does it come and go?